# What is wrong with my approach to this probability problem?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Problem: A hat has 40 slips of paper, each has the number 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, or 10, with each occurring 4 times. 4 slips are drawn out of the bag at random without replacement.

Find: The probability that 2 slips contain the number $a$ and 2 slips contain the number $b$, with $b \neq a$.

My approach is to first pick a slip, and let this slip be $a$. This can be done in 40 ways. Next, pick $a$ again. This can be done in 3 ways. Then, I pick a slip not equal to $a$. This can be done in 36 ways, and let this slip be $b$. Finally, I pick $b$ again. This can be done in 3 ways.

The probability is $\dfrac{40 \cdot 3 \cdot 36 \cdot 3}{40 \cdot 39 \cdot 38 \cdot 37} = \dfrac{54}{9139}$.

The second approach is to pick 2 values out of 10, and let the 2 values be $a$ and $b$. There are $\dbinom{4}{2}$ ways to pick $a$, and $\dbinom{4}{2}$ ways to pick $b$. There are $\dbinom{40}{4}$ ways to pick the 4 numbers, so the probability is $\dfrac{\binom{10}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{40}{4}} = \dfrac{162}{9139}$. This is the correct answer.

What is wrong with the first approach?

Comment: Given four slips labeled $a$, $a$, $b$, $b$, ordered at random, is it always the case that the first two in the ordering are equal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've computed the probability of drawing numbers in the order $aabb$; you didn't count draws of the form $abab$ or $abba$. If you add those probabilities, your method should give the correct answer.